# Как в выборке задать значение колонке 1 или 0 в зависимости от существования в ней значения?

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть запрос на выборку:

```
SELECT t.id, t.alias, t.name, at.tag_id as status
FROM tbl_tag t LEFT JOIN tbl_article_tags at
     ON t.id = at.tag_id
```

Нужно, чтобы он вернул результат, в котором колонка status будет заполняться 1 (если в ячейке есть значение) или 0 (если в ячейке NULL). Как такое реализовать?

Comment: `case when isnull(status)=1 then 0 else 1 end` так попробуйте

Comment: Суть я уловил, но ваш вариант не работает. Так по моему будет правильнее в плане синтаксиса
`CASE WHEN status IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END`, но тоже не хочет работать

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT t.id, t.alias, t.name, at.tag_id as status,
       case when at.tag_id is null then 0 else 1 end
FROM tbl_tag t LEFT JOIN tbl_article_tags at
     ON t.id = at.tag_id
```

Comment: Работает, только помимо колонок `id, alias, name, status`, добавилась колонка с именем `case when at.tag_id is null then 0 else 1 end`

Comment: Исправил таким образом: SELECT t.id, t.alias, t.name,
       case when at.tag_id is null then 0 else 1 end AS status
FROM tbl_tag t LEFT JOIN tbl_article_tags at
     ON t.id = at.tag_id

Answer (score 4):

Вот такое решение (проверил, работает на MySQL 5.5.50):

```
select
  t.id, t.alias, t.name
  case when isnull(at.tag_id) then 0 else 1 end,
  case when at.tag_id is null then 0 else 1 end, -- идентично
  at.tag_id -- для проверки
from
  tbl_tag t
left join
  tbl_article_tags at on t.id = at.tag_id
```

Comment: Не работает... у меня MySQL 5.5.47